# How to pass a vertex array as an argument in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I have the code below and I want to pass an array meshVerts into the method below:

```
- (GLuint)make:(float *)cubeVerts {

    GLuint _vertexArray;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVerts), cubeVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

}
```

However that doesn't seem to work for me? Is there anything I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: How is this not working? Any error message? Also... you are doing nothing with `meshVerts`...

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Anyways, you're not using the argument of the method at all...

Comment: meshVerts is actually cubeVerts

Comment: Sorry I fixed the post. Notice when I debugged, cubeVerts does not show me the array of loat, it instead shows a float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my typo in the post... Here is how I managed to fix it:

```
- (GLuint)make:(float[])meshVerts withSizeOfMeshVerts:(int)sizeMeshVerts
{
        GLuint _vertexArray;
        GLuint _vertexBuffer;

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

        glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeMeshVerts, meshVerts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```